# Why is UDP used for DNS requests and not TCP?

Tags: networking, dns, udp, protocols

Why is UDP usually used for DNS requests instead of TCP?

I know that we could use TCP, but why UDP is the default protocol? Are there any reasons for that, or it is just for design purposes?

Comment: TCP can be, and is used, for DNS, too. See _[RFC 7766](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7766)_ that explains: "_The majority of DNS server operators already support TCP, and the default configuration for most software implementations is to support TCP. The primary audience for this document is those implementors whose limited support for TCP restricts interoperability and hinders deployment of new DNS features. This document therefore updates the core DNS protocol specifications such that support for TCP is henceforth a REQUIRED part of a full DNS protocol implementation._"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, it is important to note that TCP can also be used for DNS. In practice, most DNS servers support both UDP and TCP, though TCP is rarely used for simple DNS queries and is reserved mainly for operations like [zone transfers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_zone_transfer).

The biggest advantage to using UDP is the performance boost. There are several reasons why TCP DNS queries are slower:

- TCP requires a connection to be established before each request, then subsequently torn down. So if it takes 20ms for a message to travel from your computer to the server and back (a time known as RTT - Round Trip Time), then a TCP query would require 3xRTT (60ms) to be fully processed - 20ms for opening the connection, 20 more ms for the query, and another 20ms to tear it down. UDP would only require one RTT, so 20ms.
- Due to TCP's connection-oriented nature, more resource are needed per-connection to store and manage TCP's state. TCP requires both the client and server to have a separate [socket](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/socket-in-computer-network/) for each and every connection.
- UDP makes it easy to deploy [anycast DNS servers](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/dns/what-is-anycast-dns/). In anycast, several servers (possibly around the world) share a single IP address - e.g. `1.1.1.1`. When you send a query to `1.1.1.1`, one of these servers (probably one of the closest ones geographically) gets it. Since TCP involves multiple packets sent back and forth, reliable anycast is harder to achieve since you need to make sure that the packets always reach the same exact server. Otherwise, they might end up reaching different servers which won't know what to do with them.
- Lower data overhead - a UDP header is tiny compared to the header TCP sends for every segment. Using UDP means sending fewer bytes.
- Simplicity - UDP is a lot simpler than TCP. TCP is optimized for long data transfers and has a bunch of complex mechanisms such as *flow control* and *congestion control* for optimizing the rate of data flow. DNS doesn't need any of these mechanisms for simple queries since the typical amount of sent data is tiny.

Comment: "though TCP is rarely used for simple DNS queries and is reserved mainly for operations like zone transfers." This is completely wrong. DNS was always, right from the beginning, defined to be used over BOTH UDP and TCP. Saying "It is UDP except it is TCP for AXFR" is the wrong way to explain things and source of a lot of problems (with some silly people filtering tcp/53 and then not understanding why some simple queries - not zone transfers - fail to work; because any conforming resolver with do UDP first and may switch to TCP if the answer is too big)

Comment: Said maybe differently/simpler about the first two and the last of the points: DNS protocol involves one query and one answer, there are no multiple exchanges, so it is stateless in nature and does not require a long standing connection, like TCP uses, that is ideal for long running exchanges. Also DNS messages are small (specially queries, and most answers) so do not have to deal with fragmentation (in theory; in practice for too big messages the exchange just switches to TCP exactly because of the guarantees this protocol can give)

Comment: You're exaggerating about the first sentence being "completely wrong". Nothing you said contradicts anything written in the answer.

Comment: I disagree with presenting things as "though TCP is rarely used for simple DNS queries and is reserved mainly for operations like zone transfers." because, from experience, people translate that to: DNS runs over UDP, and I can filter TCP because I don't want zone transfers. So I prefer: "DNS runs over UDP and TCP". Period. There is no need AT ALL to discuss zone transfers.

Comment: Otherwise please define, with numbers, "rarely" in "TCP is rarely used". How much rarely? Why? In which occasions?

Answer (score 5):

UDP is default protocol because in most cases, and when DNS was designed, an exchange is a single question/response, each part fitting into a small 512 bytes packet, so there is no need to establish a long running connection, where TCP needs first a 3-way handshake before exchanging any data.

Hence in most cases UDP gives better performances and DNS is time sensitive.

But then of course UDP is easier to spoof than TCP and bigger packets can be a problem.